# Converting dates in column of a data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

I am having problems converting a column of imported dates in a data frame, represented as characters in a different date format, into date objects in that same data frame. Here is a toy example:

```
xx <- data.frame(A = c(10, 15, 20), B = c("10/15/2010", "9/8/2015", "8/5/2013"))
```

If I print xx,

```
   A          B
1 10 10/15/2010
2 15   9/8/2015
3 20   8/5/2013
```

I apply:

```
xx[, "B"] <- sapply(xx[, "B"], function(x) {as.Date(x, 
           format = "%m/%d/%Y", origin = "1970-01-01")})
```

and I get:

```
   A     B
1 10 14897
2 15 16686
3 20 15922
```

If I look at the mode of column B, it is numeric, not date. No matter what I try I cannot seem to get a result that converts column B to a date type. I can always add:

```
xx[, "B"] <- as.Date(xx[, "B"])
```

but there must be a way to do this in one statement.

Comment: This will create a zoo series: `library(zoo); B <- read.zoo(xx, index = "B", format = "%m/%d/%Y")`  This will convert that to a data frame `fortify.zoo(B)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only one column to convert, you can do

```
xx$B <- as.Date(xx$B, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

If you have multiple columns use `lapply` instead of `sapply`

```
cols <- 2
xx[cols] <- lapply(xx[cols], as.Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

---

Or using `lubridate` where you don't need to specify the format argument.

```
xx$B <- lubridate::mdy(xx$B)
```

Comment: My mistake. My example shows only one column but in fact I have a vector of column names in the data frame I am converting, so my sapply function actually looks like: xx[ , vector_of_names] <- sapply(xx[, vector_of_names], fun ......

Comment: @Ernie yes, I have updated the answer with `lapply`. It should work for multiple columns now. `xx[vector_of_names] <- lapply(xx[vector_of_names], as.Date, "%m/%d/%Y")`